# Different projects at the same company - break them apart on the resume or keep them in the same block?

Tags: resume

I have had two very different projects over my years at the company.  I'd like to break it into two different blocks on my resume, but there are two reasons I'm considering not to.  1) I had the same job title for both, though the job and project were different.  2) I think recruiters may look at the top block, see that it's only a year long, and not bother to look at the rest.  They'll never learn that I was at the company for more than a year.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: After further review, apparently this is on topic, so apologies to you.  I retracted my VTC.

Answer (score 7):

I've handled this by making the project name part of the heading:

July 2005 - June 2007 - Senior Developer - Web Security Project

[detail here]

October 2001 - June 2005 - Senior Developer - Offsite Hosting Project

[detail here]

This way you focus on the work performed and your part in it, without confusing the reader.

Comment: Nice solution..

Answer (score 3):

You could first list the total amount of time you were at the company, followed by sub headers for the projects. You could also list any non-official titles for those projects

January 2010 - July 2017 - Senior Developer - ABC Corp.

Project A - January 2010 - December 2011 - Developer

[text]

Project B - December 2011 - July 2017 - Project Manager

[text]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your years of experience, if these were older roles then I would bunch them together to enhance your long service loyalty, if they are your most recent roles then splitting them out only makes sense if they are very different jobs.

You state that your job title is unchanged, in that scenario I would put your job title & full service length together in the heading & only then describe the two projects in the detail of the job role.

This way you can demonstrate your length of service at a glance & your adaptability across multiple projects in the detail.